# How to Filter the magento abandoned cart report collection

Tags: php, magento

I am using this code to get all the abandoned carts.

```
$storeIds = array(1);
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/quote_collection');
    $collection->prepareForAbandonedReport($storeIds);
    $collection->load();
```

What I want is that to get the carts not older than some specific date, I have also tried code below to achieve it, but its not working.

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array("main_table.created_at"=>Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 week'))));
```

Another thing how can I addAttributeToselect() to get the required data, not all.If someone can also provide the answers with some other filter examples it will be very grateful.Thanks in advance

Comment: In need same code for Magento 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after alot of searching I finally found the way to do it. The function prepareForAbandonedReport() is doing all the filteration steps, so I open the file containing this function, copied its code and used it in my code and altered it according to my needs. Here is the code I used,I hope this will help someone.

```
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/quote_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('items_count', array('neq' => '0'))
        ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.is_active', '1')
        ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.created_at', array('gt' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-2 month'))))
        ->addSubtotal($storeIds, null)
        ->addCustomerData(null)
        ->setOrder('updated_at')
        ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('in' => $storeIds));
    $collection->load();
```

Comment: @muhmmad mannan for 1 year report from current how do we get?

Comment: @NagarajuK update this line in the above code.
 ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.created_at', array('gt' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-12 month'))))

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code this may help -

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/quote_collection');
$collection->prepareForAbandonedReport();
$output = $collection->load()->toArray();
```

Comment: Please ready the actual requirements, I am already getting the abandoned cart data from the code I have provided, I want the collection to be filtered according to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Since this answer help me a lot, i'll share my own solution (tested in Magento EE 1.13.1.0):

1. Override `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Quote_Collection`
2. Create `_filterDate()` method:

   ```
   public function _filterDate($key, $filter) 
   {
       if (array_key_exists($key, $filter)) {
           $filterDate = $filter[$key];
           if (array_key_exists('from', $filterDate)) {
               $fromRawDate    = $filter[$key]['from'];
               $dateFrom       = str_replace('/', '-', $fromRawDate);
               $dateStart      = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateFrom)) . ' 00:00:00';
           }
           if (array_key_exists('to', $filterDate)) {
               $toRawDate      = $filter[$key]['to'];
               $dateTo         = str_replace('/', '-', $toRawDate);
               $dateEnd        = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateTo)) . ' 23:59:59';
           }

           if ( ! empty($dateStart) && ! empty($dateEnd) ) {
               $this->addFieldToFilter('`main_table`.`' . $key . '`', array('from' => $dateStart, 'to' => $dateEnd));
           } else if ( ! empty($dateStart) && empty($dateEnd) ) {
               $this->addFieldToFilter('`main_table`.`' . $key . '`', array('from' => $dateStart));
           } else if ( ! empty($dateEnd) && empty($dateStart) ) {
               $this->addFieldToFilter('`main_table`.`' . $key . '`', array('to' => $dateEnd));
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Edit `prepareForAbandonedReport()` and use `_filterDate()`:

   ```
   public function prepareForAbandonedReport($storeIds, $filter = null)
   {
       self::_filterDate('created_at', $filter); // Used to filter created_at field
       self::_filterDate('updated_at', $filter); // Used to filter updated_at field

       $this->addFieldToFilter('items_count', array('neq' => '0'))
           ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.is_active', '1')
           ->addSubtotal($storeIds, $filter)
           ->addCustomerData($filter)
           ->setOrder('updated_at');

       if (is_array($storeIds) && !empty($storeIds)) {
           $this->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('in' => $storeIds));
       }

       return $this;
   }
   ```